# Rabbit MQ events concurrency and sync

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

During our development we faced the following scenario:
A event produced generating events chains in certain order:
Lets say 
*Create Item1, Update Item 1, Finish Item 1, 
Create Item2, Update Item 2, Finish Item 2.*

Keep in mind that events for items 1 and 2 are dispatched in parallel. 
We need to handle events of Item 1 and 2 sequentially for each item without blocking unrelated operations e.g. Create Item 1 and create Item 2may run in parallel while CreateItem1 and Update Item 1 must run sequentially.

The main question is how can we achieve such behavior without creating a dedicated queue for each item?
The number of items is unknown.
There are multiple producers and multiple consumers handling events.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: don't emit those events parallely. If `Update Item` event has to be processed after `Create Item` event then it is natural that `Create Item` consumer should emit `Update Item` event after it finished processing `Create Item` event.

BTW: Having a separate queue for each item only works if you have one consumer on such queue and if you can guarantee that events are emitted in correct order.